# Создаю прогу только для вертикальной ориентации

Tags: android, java

Создаю прогу только для вертикальной ориентации, в итоге если попытаться переворачивать телефон пока прога запускаеться она запуститься в горизонтальной ориентации, а еще и был случай когда прога создала 2 копию активити поверх первой, почему так происходит?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.PoemsAndFace"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
             android:theme="@style/MyTheme.NoTitleBar.CustomBackground"
             android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <activity android:name="MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Authors"/>
    <activity android:name=".OutDataAuthors"/>
    <activity android:name=".PageAuthors"/>
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: У <application> нет атрибута android:screenOrientation

Comment: Как нету если он пишется, ахаха

Comment: @xTIGRx, я тоже в своей жизни много забавных вещей писал

Comment: Есть 20 активити мне что тогда для каждого писать android:screenOrientation чтоли, как для всех то поставить сразу?

Comment: @xTIGRx,

>для каждого писать что ли?

Да.

>как для всех-то поставить?

`Ctrl+C   Ctrl+V`

Comment: @xTIGRx
> Как нету если он пишется, ахаха
На заборе тоже много чего пишется, но с [документацией][1] не поспоришь...


  [1]: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Есть 20 активити

Что-то мне подсказывает, что можно использовать фрагменты  
Если не фрагменты, то определить базовый класс MyActivity, и у него в onCreate() после super.onCreate() написать

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

И от этого класса наследовать свои Активити